# Changing windows default keyboard shortcuts without external programs

Tags: windows-10

is there a way to change Windows's default shortcuts?
I'm trying to change`Windows+Space` shortcut to close programs (basically, ALT+F4)

I don't want to use Lua Macros or AHK

Comment: It's not possible to change the particular shortcut with using third-party software

Comment: Really? it needs to be stored somewhere in windows files... Even the sound files can be found and altered